# How can I add a text beneath a textbox

Tags: asp.net, forms, textbox, label

I am developing a ASP.Net form. As shown in below picture I need to put small text message just beneath a text box. (message is highlighted as yellow in image). How can I achieve this? Please note the text message must be close to textbox exactly as shown.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code example from the structure in order to be properly answered

Comment: Platform added. Thanks for the point.

Comment: Please provide your current markup.